# How to use cucumber correctly?

Tags: testing, cucumber, bdd, acceptance-testing, cucumber-junit

For example, the Yathzee game has a score card with 13 categories, when I want to test scoring, should I just create a .feature file and write 13 scenarios to test each category, or create .feature file for each categroy?

Comment: Does all those 13 categories information shows up on the same page/ does have the same flow to get the required information? If the yes is yes, then I would recommend using the data table (Scenario Outline - examples table)/ scenario step with table.

Answer (score 0):

As its an feature you can define each category as one feature if they are all along different.

If the these categories are not so diffferent and shared a same steps then use **scenario outline** in feature file and pass the category name, data and other required details using `example table`